# remove the value of the Upload editor in client-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, file

In my Apllication uploading the file is optional , the user should be able to select a file to upload 
or remove it and post nothing

I just want to add an X icon calls a JS to set the value to null .

Thank You

```
<div>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.File , "File" )


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#file").val(null);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" />
<button>remove</button>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/musugkne/1/)**